# MS Graph API New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest : Error 403

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to assign some roles **via PIM** on my subscription to a group.
I use PowerShell, I'm connected on MS Graph API with a **Service Principal** (`Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token`).
I'am able to do some simple requests like `Get-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessResource`.
But the command to assign roles via PIM, `New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest`, return a forbidden issue.

My ServicePrincipal is User Access Admin on my subscription, and has a lot of API Permissions.
**The same command works with my personal account**, which has UAA and the same API Permissions.

I haven't a lot of information with the debug parameter.
Just only:

```
Status Code: Forbidden

Body:
{
  'error': {
    'code': 'UnauthorizedAccessException',
    'message': 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.',
    'innerError': {
      'date': '2024-01-26T17:21:09',
      'request-id': '96d7652f-4f3e-464b-93c3-699152633546',
      'client-request-id': '556a7966-3082-4e9c-ac5a-e12f017f098e'
    }
  }
}
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroleassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell#permissions) and `New-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessRoleAssignmentRequest` doesn't support application permissions.

According to the same doc, the Privileged Identity Management (PIM) API for Azure resources will be deprecated soon.

The migration guide is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagement-root?view=graph-rest-beta#migrate-to-the-azure-resource-manager-arm-pim-api-for-azure-resource-roles

but it's not clear whether you should use either

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleassignmentschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell

or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleeligibilityschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell